# PHP regex - check if string contains a given value with certain count of random digits in the end

Tags: php, arrays, regex, match, contain

I have few strings in an array:

```
$array = array('BE001 FIRST', 'BE01 SECOND', 'SV001 THIRD');

foreach ($array as $item) {
    // preg_match('', $item);
}
```

I would like to get an array element if it contains "BE" + 3 of any digits right after. In this case 1st array element.

I am not familiar to `regex`, but I saw examples how to match a given value, but not a given value with the certain count of random digits at the end. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_grep`:

```
$array = array('BE001 FIRST', 'BE01 SECOND', 'SV001 THIRD');
$res = preg_grep('/^BE\d{3}\b/', $array);
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => BE001 FIRST
)
```

Comment: why not add `B` before `E`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Problem in the interface between keyboard and chair ;-)

Comment: The `^` is an assumption that is not actually justified from the questions wording ;-) But certainly this is the best answer!

Comment: @arkascha: Maybe, only OP can say.

Comment: @Toto lol, actually  no. _Strictly_ speaking it is _not_ requested. That is something _we_ can say. But indeed it is something the OP might want to narrow down.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```
<?php
$input = ['BE001 FIRST', 'BE01 SECOND', 'SV001 THIRD', 'BE1234 FOURTH'];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function(&$entry) use (&$output) {
    if (preg_match('/BE\d{3}([^\d]|$)/', $entry)) {
        $output[] = $entry;
    }
});
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BE001 FIRST
)
```